# Specifying a high quality background image in a Unity 3D game for iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, unity-game-engine, textures

First question from me, please be kind :)

We are having an iOS game created for us by a developer using Unity3D. We are testing his progress on the iPhone and also iPad.

On the iPad the background image we have supplied is very blurry. He says that he has to use a background image at 1024 x 768 pixels, which looks OK on the iPhone, but terrible on iPad.

Its a simple background texture, as a JPEG, and it doesn't move or do anything clever. Is there not a way of making this better, perhaps:

1. Specifying different background images for different devices
2. Using a larger image which is scaled down on iPhone, but shows at its natural size on an iPad
3. Using a larger image which fills the screen on an iPad, but on iPhone you only see a small part of the image (the rest just goes off the edges out of view)
4. Specify a "tile" of the background which seamlessly repeats, so nothing gets stretched on the iPad, we just get more of these tiles to fill the screen

Any other solutions we can try? Currently he is saying that nothing can be done, iPad will be blurry. Which I find a bit odd. Surely there's ways to make it better?

Many thanks!
Steve

Comment: which version of ipad are you talking about?does it have a retina display?

Comment: Sorry yes, should have said. Checking on an iphone 5, and ipad 3 so yes, Retina display

Answer (score 1):

`Retina` display(used on `iPad 3` devices) has a double resolution respect a iPad's 2 display. It's actually `2.048x1.536`  against `1024x768`. So that's way a texture resolution of 1028x768 isn't enough (a 2x magnification will occur).

`Unity3D` supports texture with a maximum resolution of `2048x2048`, so you should be able to see a full screen texture without needing any magnification.

> Specifying different background images for different devices

That's possible. Maybe the best solution when the device's screens have different proportions. I'd go this way.

> Using a larger image which is scaled down on iPhone, but shows at its
>   natural size on an iPad

That's also possible but `iPad 3` and `iPhone 5` have different proportion(`1136x640`), so the downscale texture won't be uniform (it may look a bit stretched).

Both solution 3 and 4 are possible, but it depends on you.

> Currently he is saying that nothing can be done, iPad will be blurry.

That's definitely not true.